# Linkedin Api Visibillity

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I spent some time without touching this Api, and now I have received the following error:

`Unpermitted fields present in REQUEST_BODY:`

It's a sharing code:

```
$link = 'https://example.com.br';
$access_token = $access_token;
$linkedin_id = $linkedin_profile_id;
$body = new \stdClass();
$body->content = new \stdClass();
$body->content->contentEntities[0] = new \stdClass();
$body->text = new \stdClass();
$body->content->contentEntities[0]->thumbnails[0] = new \stdClass();
$body->content->contentEntities[0]->entityLocation = $link;
$body->content->contentEntities[0]->thumbnails[0]->resolvedUrl = "https://example.com.br/img/logo-header-120x50.png";
$body->content->title = 'Example';
$body->owner = 'urn:li:person:'.$linkedin_id;
$body->text->text = 'Kasum';
$body->visibility = new \stdClass();
$body->visibility->code = new \stdClass();
$body->visibility->code = 'anyone';//<-------------that is a line error
$body_json = json_encode($body, true);

try {
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.linkedin.com']);
    $response = $client->request('POST', '/v2/shares', [
        'headers' => [
            "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $access_token,
            "Content-Type"  => "application/json",
            "x-li-format"   => "json"
        ],
        'body' => $body_json,
    ]);

    if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 201) {
        echo 'Error: '. $response->getLastBody()->errors[0]->message;
    }

    echo 'Post is shared on LinkedIn successfully';
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(). ' for link '. $link;
}
```

As indicated in the code, the visibility field triggers this error

Without it, sharing occurs, but with visibility only for connections. That way the post loses the share button.

Is it no longer allowed to configure this field, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Well, if it's [share API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api) you're using, I don't see "visibility" mentioned anywhere. There is `visibleToGuest` (which is `true` by default).

Comment: @El_Vanja to many years i stop my api to linkedin, i can see many changes, and they documentation is so week, would you know to indicate me some guide content for automatic posting in my profile

Comment: @El_Vanja tks u lightup my mind... Now is `ugcPosts` end point... tks and tks again and again..  so many hours in this problem tks again u have light in your fingers